# HTTPS works fine from android 7, but doesnt works in android 6, - using ssl certificate

Tags: android, react-native

Following android docs i have used network-config  with domain config
to attach and allowed specific domains.

Https works properly fine now with android  7 and above
But it doesn't work with android 6 or probably below(not checked yet)

Please share your views.

Comment: Please share the logcat or any error that you see while running your program.

Comment: @ReazMurshed . shows me status null, and   error - Type  Network request failed.

Comment: sorry for late comment but could u solve it?